# How to publish beta App (TestFlight) on the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have deployed an iOS app on the store using TestFlight (Beta Testing)

https://youtu.be/DLvdZtTAJrE

Does anyone have an idea to publish this beta app on the App Store in development status and user should not allow to comment and rate on that.

Comment: Only released apps are suitable for the App Store. They must be fully functional and you cannot opt out of App Store features, like reviews. You can share a public TestFlight link to allow an "open beta"

Comment: "I have deployed an iOS app on the store using TestFlight" - No, you haven't.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok thanks for your response, Can we hide the comments section for on our app on App Store?

Comment: No. You cannot.